# Plot N Results with Python and NLTK

Tags: python, plot, nltk

I am using NLTK with Python to analyze some data. I have constructed a `FreqDist` with a list of strings from a corpus and there are around 1,000 words in the result set. I want to display only those words that have a count over X, because when I plot all of the values with `myfreqdist.plot()` it can't fit all of the values and I don't see what I can pass into plot to limit the result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to limit the number of words to show in the plot, you can specify the number of the most frequent words to visualize as the first argument of the `plot()` function. 
In your case, you have first to compute how many words have a frequency bigger than X. 
So you can use an approach as the following

```
 num = len([a for a in myfreqdist if myfreqdist[a]>X])
 myfreqdist.plot(num)
```

In this case num is the number of words that appear more than X times. Given this number, you can use it in the `plot()` function.

Comment: Somehow I missed the fact that the plot function takes "num"! Thanks a lot!